# c- recvfrom error 22

Tags: c, linux, sockets, linaro

Okay first here is the code:

```
int recvMast_sock;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
socklen_t cli_len;
if ((recvMast_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1)
  {
    critErr("listen:socket=");
  }

fillSockaddrAny(&serv_addr, UDP_NODE_LISTEN_PORT);// fills the sockaddr_in works fine elsewhere

if ((bind(recvMast_sock, (struct sockaddr*) &serv_addr, sizeof serv_addr)) < 0)
  {
    critErr("listen:bind recv_mast_sock:");
  }
recvReturn_i = recvfrom(recvMast_sock, &recvBuff[0], (size_t)1, 0, (struct   sockaddr*) &cli_addr, &cli_len);
if(recvReturn_i <0)
        printf("recv error%d\n",errno);
```

`critErr` is a function to handle errors which also includes a print of the error and an `exit`.

This runs in a thread, if this is of any relevance. If I compile and run this on a Zedboard (ZYNQ-7000 SoC) which has an ARM Cortex A9 and Linaro Linux (based on precise Ubuntu). It prints error `22` but still has the received value in `recvBuff[0]`.

Running this in my VM with xubuntu it works fine.

Error `22` equals `EINVAL` which is described as Invalid argument.

In the manpage of [`recvfrom(2)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/recvfrom/) it states `EINVAL` means that the `MSG_OOB` flag is set but I don't use any flags (passing `0`).

Before leaving on friday I started an `apt-get` upgrade because I hope it is a faulty library or something like this.  I can check back at monday but maybe someone here has another idea what is wrong.

Comment: I highly doubt this has something to do with the architecture, instead check that the setup is ok.

Comment: setup in what kind of sense. The installation of the linux or the hardware? Networking works normal except for that. Its not the first call to a recvfrom.

Comment: Both probably, but I would first check the linux instalation. Are they both the same Ubuntu?

Comment: As stated the VM runs a xubuntu (15.04) and the other one is linaro (which is based on precise-Ubuntu)

Comment: It seems like an old one, I am no Ubuntu fan but precise is old from what I remember. There might indeed be a bug in some library function. Try installing *linaro* on the virtual machine and check if it still reproduces the problem, if it doesn't you can *maybe* blame the architecture, but I don't see how this particular problem can be related to that.

Comment: Mhh i might try that. But linaro is a linux for ARM-processors. Well let's see what monday brings me.  I should have titled this with the architecture because i thought there might have been flaws in the libraries or gcc for ARM at some point or you have to care about something on ARM. Whatever...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not caused by the OS or the architecture. The function was not called on the x86-system because of a blocked mutex. So I didn't got the error there.

The problem was that I passed the socket to this function from 'main' (which i did not state in the question because I thought it was irrelevant, my bad...)
In 'main' I used it and used it in this function. Even though it was mutually exclusive, there was this error.

Remy's answer was also relevant but not a solution to the problem. Not setting cli_len beforehand just leads to a cut of sockaddr if its too small. No error was generated for that.

Answer (score 6):

You need to initialize `cli_len` before passing it to `recvfrom()`:

```
cli_len = sizeof(cli_addr);
```

You are not initializing it, so it has a random value. If that value happens to be < `sizeof(cli_addr)`, `recvfrom()` can fail with `EINVAL`, or at least truncate the address, because it thinks `cli_addr` is not large enough to receive the client address. If the value is vastly larger than `sizeof(cli_addr)`, `recvfrom()` might consider the buffer to be outside of the valid memory range.

You have to tell `recvfrom()` how large `cli_addr` actually is.  This is clearly stated in the [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recvfrom):

> **The argument addrlen is a value-result argument, which the caller should initialize before the call to the size of the buffer associated with src_addr, and modified on return to indicate the actual size of the source address**. The returned address is truncated if the buffer provided is too small; in this case, addrlen will return a value greater than was supplied to the call.

So you have to initialize `cli_len` with the total size of `cli_addr` before calling `recvfrom()`, then `recvfrom()` updates `cli_len` with the size of the address that was actually written into `cli_addr`.  `cli_addr` can be larger than the address, for instance when using a `sockaddr_storage` structure to accept either IPv4 or IPv6 addresses on a dual-stack socket.  In the example in the question, an IPv4 socket is being used, so `cli_len` must be initialized to a value >= `sizeof(sockaddr_in)`.